# Pokemon go disappearing Magmar

Tags: pokemon-go

When I went to power up my Magmar I heard the cry and everything that follows a power up but when I went to view my Pokemon inventory the Magmar was gone and hasn't come back. This happened again shortly after with my Jolteon but it returned shortly after. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I've not heard of this happening. If your inventory is sorted by CP then the magmar simply moved position in the list after your power up.